# Send notification to NotificationCenter.default.addObserver

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

Im currently developing a Textfield with placeholder. For the text editor, we using UITextView as follow inside UIViewRepresentable protocol.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let tv = UITextView()
        .....
        tv.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // Creating placeholder since we need it
        let placeholderLabel = UILabel()
        placeholderLabel.text = placeholder
        .....
        placeholderLabel.isHidden = !text.isEmpty
        tv.addSubview(placeholderLabel)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
            placeholderLabel.isHidden = !tv.text.isEmpty
        }
        
        return tv
    }
```

Since we have NotificationCenter.default.addObserver, I believe its expected when user typed on this text editor -> delete using native (by keyboard) -> return the placeholder.

```
placeholderLabel.isHidden = !tv.text.isEmpty
```

But, the problem is I have button to remove text editor content and since its not inside text editor (on different file inside Text Field container) then the notification didn't triggered.
Looks something like this

```
@ViewBuilder func removableBtn() -> some View {
        if !text.isEmpty && removable {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    text = ""
                }
             }
         }
}
```

Based on current code, Im aware its return empty when removable is tapped because its still return `text = ""` . My question is how to pass this notification from `removableBtn` into the `NotificationCenter`?

My expecttaion is if !text.isEmpty then we can either delete the content using native or we can delete by using removable button. This removable should have same output as using native deletion.

Comment: Why are you not using `TextField`? Since iOS 16, it supports a placeholder out of the box.

Comment: If you do need `UITextView`, set the `delegate` and use the `UITextViewDelegate` methods instead of `UITextView.textDidChangeNotification` to be notified about text changes.